# Asp.Net MVC custom routing interrupt default routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

My routes are not working don't know why. When I try attribute routing it works for for that action but breaks default routing for other controller or actions. I only want to change routing for an index action method of a controller CMS I want it like **[Route("{countrycode}/{id}")]**. but when I do this default route breaks for other index action methods of other controllers.
For example: When I use **[Route("{countrycode}/{id}")]** on cms controller's index action then route breaks for Home and other controllers index action methods so I have to call the index methods explicitly like **/Home/Index** instead of **/Home** otherwise it throw an error. Thanks in advance.